# Excel - How to pull data from a sheet and list/count on another sheet by date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

On my primary sheet, each row has a date field in the "A" column and a drop-down menu in the "B" column with 1 of 4 options (ex: "cat" "dog" "cow" "pig").

What I'd like to do is setup a new sheet that will pull data from the primary sheet.  "A" column would be a date field, "B" column is Cat, "C" is Dog, "D" is Cow, & "E" is Pig.  Each row would list a date from the primary sheet, then give a count of each instance of Cat/Dog/Cow/Pig options.

Any thoughts on how I can set this up?  The 1st screenshot below shows what the primary sheet data would look like, and the 2nd shows how I'd like the new sheet calculations to look like.

Primary Sheet Example:

[image]

New Sheet Example:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a canonical use case for a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

I've set up [a spreadsheet in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O6RfTt2aw3TCvUm823P1_Z2mswEvThDKrSDl6jTuiCY/edit?usp=sharing) for you that demonstrates the concept. You can download the sheet to .xls or .xlsx and it should faithfully transfer the pivot table to Excel format.

Just look at the "Pivot Table 1" sheet. It correctly uses the `COUNTA()` function to summarize the data. The best part is that the columns and rows are dynamically generated based on the input data, and it doesn't depend on the input data being sorted correctly.

You can do this with worksheet functions too, but it's extremely difficult to replicate all the niceties of the pivot table without using a pivot table:

- The columns are automatically created for each unique value in the original column B. *This is SUPER hard to do without using a Pivot Table* and may require VBA code otherwise.
- The rows are automatically created for each unique date, and you can custom sort the rows in the pivot table without changing the source data.
- If you were to change from string-based values ("Cow", "Cat") to numerical values (7, 16, 556), you could change the aggregate function in the pivot table from `COUNTA` to `SUM` and very easily sum up the data instead of counting it. This change would be less trivial if you were manually reproducing what a pivot table does using worksheet functions.

Overall there is no good justification for *not* using pivot tables when they solve your problem, so you should learn how to use them. Worksheet functions are the wrong approach to solving this problem.

---

Here's a walkthrough of how to do it in Excel 2016 (click on the image to make it larger):

[image]

Unrelatedly, if you like the GIF and want to know how I did that, I used the free tool [ScreenToGif](http://screentogif.com).

Comment: Boom!!!! Pivot Tables are my new best friend.  Thanks so much for the help - and for putting together the walkthrough!